# Issue during reboot SGX disabled and APCI BIOS Error

Tags: linux, linux-mint, reboot, acpi, sgx

Tried rebooting mint using command “sudo reboot” during reload processes stopped because “SGX is disabled by bios” and there is a bug in ACPI (ACPI Bios Error(bug): Could not resolve symbol [TBTS], AE_NOT_FOUND)
Does anyone know why it happened or how to fix it?
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvwpR.jpg)

Comment: You can use this project to enable sgx: https://github.com/intel/sgx-software-enable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the Kernel panic issue by following these steps:

- I accessed the advanced options in GRUB.
- I selected 'Ubuntu with linux-generic (recovery mode),' which brought me to the login page.

However, after entering my password, I encountered a login loop.
To resolve this problem, I followed the commands outlined in this blog post: https://www.howtogeek.com/892137/how-to-fix-the-ubuntu-login-loop/.

**The issue was caused by a full file system**. I resolved it by deleting what was unnecessary, and afterward, everything worked perfectly.